# Преобразование String в double

Tags: c++, массивы, структуры

Как мне преобразовать числа string в double через atof сразу в массив?

[image: Сам код]

[image: Типичная ошибка]

Comment: Вы же сами ответили как. В чём вопрос? Может не знаете про `.c_str()`?

Comment: Код и тексты ошибок следует вставлять как текст.

Answer (score 2):

Раз Вы указали, что код на С++, то и используйте средства С++. У `string` из STL есть вполне удобные функции для преобразования в числа: `stoi(), stod()` и т.д. Единственное ограничение - нужно использовать С++11 (или новее).
[Вот пример использования:](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stod/)

```
#include <iostream>   // std::cout
#include <string>     // std::string, std::stod

int main ()
{
  std::string orbits ("365.24 29.53");
  std::string::size_type sz;     // alias of size_t

  double earth = std::stod (orbits,&sz);
  double moon = std::stod (orbits.substr(sz));
  std::cout << "The moon completes " << (earth/moon) << " orbits per Earth year.\n";
  return 0;
}
```